# how to duplicate a row field on a condition in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I expose my problem :
This is my table :

```
id      ticket_id   Severity    Changed_field    Last_modified_date
1       ticket1     Minor                        01/01/2013
2       ticket1                 Category         02/01/2013
3       ticket1                 Status           03/01/2013
4       ticket1     Major       Severity         04/01/2013
5       ticket1                 Assigned_to      05/01/2013
```

I look to have :

```
id      ticket_id   Severity    Changed_field    Last_modified_date
1       ticket1     Minor                        01/01/2013
2       ticket1     Minor       Category         02/01/2013
3       ticket1     Minor       Status           03/01/2013
4       ticket1     Major       Severity         04/01/2013
5       ticket1     Major       Assigned_to      05/01/2013
```

or :

```
id      ticket_id   Severity    Changed_field    Last_modified_date
1       ticket1     Major                        01/01/2013
2       ticket1     Major       Category         02/01/2013
3       ticket1     Major       Status           03/01/2013
4       ticket1     Major       Severity         04/01/2013
5       ticket1     Major       Assigned_to      05/01/2013
```

Comment: What result do you really want? How it would be formed? I can suppose the first use the last `Severity` which is not null, but I can't be sure, as you didn't even tried to explain what you wanted. About the second, I have no idea...

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT 
     id
    ,ticket_id
    ,CASE WHEN COALESCE(Severity, '') = ''
             THEN 'Minor'
             ELSE Severity
     END AS Severity
    ,Changed_field
    ,Last_modified_date
FROM YOUR_Table
```